# Indicating recession with grey bar

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series

I have yearly data on several economic variables (GDP, interest rates, inflation etc.) that are imported from Excel. I want to show the years were the economy was officially in a recession. So I have tried using the [recessionplot](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/econ/recessionplot.html) function but I can't get it to work.

I think my problem is that my time variable is not properly defined. As of now, I have a variable called 'Year' and it is an array (113x1) consisting of years (1900-2012). If I understood correctly I need to transform this using datenum. So my first question is: how do I use datenum on an array of years?

Also, it is my understanding that recessionplot uses data from NBER (i.e specific to the US), is there any way I can specify my time periods at which there was a recession in the UK?

If there is an easier way of doing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MATLAB has fantastic [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/) and you should learn to use it.

---

> how do I use datenum on an array of years?

From the [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) documentation:

```
Y = 1900:2012;
M = 1;
D = 1;
DateNumber = datenum(Y,M,D);
```

---

> is there any way I can specify my time periods at which there was a recession in the UK?

From the [`recessionplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/recessionplot.html) documentation:

> `'recessions'` -- Recession data
>
> Recession data indicating the beginning and end of historical recessions, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of `'recessions'` and a `numRecessions`-by-`2` matrix of serial date numbers. The first column indicates the beginning of the recession, and the second column indicates the end of the recession. The default recession data is the U.S. recession data in `Data_Recessions.mat`, reported by the National Bureau of Economic Research.

So you need something like this:

```
my_recessions = [1920, 1930; 1980, 1990];
recessionplot('recessions', my_recessions);
```

The `recessionplot` documentation also includes a full example (with usage of `datenum` too!). You should run this example and experiment with it to better understand how to use these functions.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. This is my first time programming so I'm still getting used to all the syntax; but you are correct, the documentation is very helpful. I have tried to follow your method but I have some further questions about saving the axes. I will edit my OP to keep things clear.

Comment: If you're just starting with MATLAB then learning to use the docs is the best tip I can give you. Also, don't edit your question with additional issues if it was answered. It is better to post a new question.

Comment: Apologies, I will undo the edit and post it as a separate question. Thanks again for the help, it is truly appreciated.

Comment: No problem :) if this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the grey check mark.